# How to analyze 'dbcc memorystatus' result in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Currently I am facing a SQL memory pressure issue. i have run `dbcc memorystatus`, here is part of my result:

```
Memory Manager                           KB
---------------------------------------- -----------
VM Reserved                              23617160
VM Committed                             14818444
Locked Pages Allocated                   0
Reserved Memory                          1024
Reserved Memory In Use                   0


Memory node Id = 0                       KB
---------------------------------------- -----------
VM Reserved                              23613512
VM Committed                             14814908
Locked Pages Allocated                   0
MultiPage Allocator                      387400
SinglePage Allocator                     3265000


MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL (node 0)       KB
---------------------------------------- -----------
VM Reserved                              16809984
VM Committed                             14184208
Locked Pages Allocated                   0
SM Reserved                              0
SM Committed                             0
SinglePage Allocator                     0
MultiPage Allocator                      408

MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR (node 0)              KB
---------------------------------------- -----------
VM Reserved                              6311612
VM Committed                             141616
Locked Pages Allocated                   0
SM Reserved                              0
SM Committed                             0
SinglePage Allocator                     1456
MultiPage Allocator                      20144

CACHESTORE_SQLCP (node 0)                KB
---------------------------------------- -----------
VM Reserved                              0
VM Committed                             0
Locked Pages Allocated                   0
SM Reserved                              0
SM Committed                             0
SinglePage Allocator                     3101784
MultiPage Allocator                      300328

Buffer Pool                              Value
---------------------------------------- -----------
Committed                                1742946
Target                                   1742946
Database                                 1333883
Dirty                                    940
In IO                                    1
Latched                                  18
Free                                     89
Stolen                                   408974
Reserved                                 2080
Visible                                  1742946
Stolen Potential                         1579938
Limiting Factor                          13
Last OOM Factor                          0
Page Life Expectancy                     5463

Process/System Counts                    Value
---------------------------------------- --------------------
Available Physical Memory                258572288
Available Virtual Memory                 8771398631424
Available Paging File                    16030617600
Working Set                              15225597952
Percent of Committed Memory in WS        100
Page Faults                              305556823
System physical memory high              1
System physical memory low               0
Process physical memory low              0
Process virtual memory low               0

Procedure Cache                          Value
---------------------------------------- -----------
TotalProcs                               11382
TotalPages                               430160
InUsePages                               28
```

Can you lead me to analyze this result ?

Is it a lot execute plan have been cached causing the memory issue or other reasons?

Answer (score 9):

This is a bit late, but perhaps it will help someone else who reads this.
From seeing `Available Virtual Memory` of `8 TB`, I can tell this is a 64 bit system - along with the absence of any references to AWE allocation.

As Lette points out, the OS itself only has `256 MB` of `Available Physical Memory`  - but that's just what's remaining, not the total amount installed.  SQL will try to use as much physical memory that's installed as possible for performance; accessing memory is by far faster than moving a disk head.

Going by `VM Committed`, SQL is using `14.1 GB` of physical memory going by `VM Committed` - I'll guess that 16 GB total of physical memory is present, accounting for OS needs, available physical memory, and 16 being a good round number.

Memory pressure is coming from two primary areas: SQL buffer pool, and SQL Plan Cache.

**SQL Buffer Pool**

About 13.5 GB of memory is benig used for the buffer pool.  Not atypical for SQL; it will try to use as much memory as it can.

**SQL Plan Cache:**

Aaccording to `11,382` ad-hoc queries query plans are cached. However, only `28` plans are in use - less than 1%.  If we map this back to CACHESTORE_SQLCP, we see an interesting story - no memory is currently being used for these plans at this time, but I think at one point it had consuming `3.24 GB` of memory. I must admit that I'm less sure of this, and would certainly appreciate a 2nd opinion on seeing 0 for VM Commmitted but values present for the allocators.

**Summary**
Since you're running SQL 2008, consider enabling [optimizing for ad hoc query plans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645587.aspx). This will help quite a bit with memory pressure if your workloads are primarily ad hoc.

[Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907877)

Comment: hi JohnW , are the values displayed by DBCC MEMORYSTATUS (Say, current value) specific to an instance of the SQL Server or to the whole SQL Server? I tried with different instances in the same SQL Server but am seeing different values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guess:

One thing that strikes me is that you have a `Working Set` of `15 GB` while the `Available Physical Memory` is only `258 MB`. I believe you should make more memory available to Sql Server. (Whether that's just moving a slider a little more to the right, and/or installing more RAM, I couldn't know.)

Comment: hi @Christoffer Lette , are the values displayed by DBCC MEMORYSTATUS (Say, current value) specific to an instance of the SQL Server or to the whole SQL Server? I tried with different instances in the same SQL Server but am seeing different values.

Comment: @Jean, I'm pretty sure that the values are instance specific. Every instance runs in its own process, and I don't think that any memory is shared between processes/instances.

Comment: @Jean BTW I find the phrases "the whole SQL Server" and "different instances in the same SQL server" somewhat unclear and/or ambiguous. Are you referring to the hardware? Or are you referring to "the sum of all instances"? The different instances are in fact completely independent SQL Servers, running in different processes with independent settings. You could uninstall one without affecting the other. You could even have several different versions of SQL Server running as separate instances on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

The docs for DBCC MEMORYSTATUS() are here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907877

They're not terribly verbose - but will, at least, give you an idea of what you're looking at.